# Volume of store sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want the top 10 stores with the highest volume(percentage) of sales and the 5 with the lowest volume(percentage) of sales in a **single report**. Here's what i have done until now

```
SELECT TOP 10 Stores.Store_ID,Suppliers$.NAME,SUM(Store.QTY*Product.PRICE) AS StoreSales
FROM Stores
     INNER JOIN Invoices$ ON Stores.store_ID=Invoices.Store_ID
     INNER JOIN InvDetails ON Invoices.INVOICE_ID=InvDetails.INVOICE_ID
     INNER JOIN Products ON Products.PRODUCT_ID=InvDetails.PRODUCT_ID

GROUP BY Stores.Store_ID,Stores.NAME 
ORDER BY StoresSales DESC
```

Comment: Your query will fail as written.  In particular, `Suppliers$` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

```
select TOP 10 ...
from ...
group by ...
order by StoresSales DESC
union 
select TOP 5 ...
from ...
group by ...
order by StoresSales ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a CTE by dividing the query in two, the first part extracts the highest and the second part the lowest

```
With c as(
    SELECT TOP 10 Stores.Store_ID,Suppliers$.NAME,SUM(Store.QTY*Product.PRICE) AS StoreSales
    ,cat = 'Max'
    FROM Stores
         INNER JOIN Invoices$ ON Stores.store_ID=Invoices.Store_ID
         INNER JOIN InvDetails ON Invoices.INVOICE_ID=InvDetails.INVOICE_ID
         INNER JOIN Products ON Products.PRODUCT_ID=InvDetails.PRODUCT_ID

    GROUP BY Stores.Store_ID,Stores.NAME 
    ORDER BY StoresSales DESC
    ),
    d as (
    SELECT TOP 5 Stores.Store_ID,Suppliers$.NAME,SUM(Store.QTY*Product.PRICE) AS StoreSales
          ,cat = 'Min'
    FROM Stores
         INNER JOIN Invoices$ ON Stores.store_ID=Invoices.Store_ID
         INNER JOIN InvDetails ON Invoices.INVOICE_ID=InvDetails.INVOICE_ID
         INNER JOIN Products ON Products.PRODUCT_ID=InvDetails.PRODUCT_ID
    GROUP BY Stores.Store_ID,Stores.NAME 
    ORDER BY StoresSales asc
    )
    Select * 
    From c 
    Union all 
    Select * 
    From d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT Stores.Store_ID, Suppliers$.NAME, SUM(Store.QTY*Product.PRICE) AS StoreSales,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Stores.Store_ID, Suppliers$.NAME ORDER BY SUM(Store.QTY*Product.PRICE) DESC) AS MAX_SEQ,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Stores.Store_ID, Suppliers$.NAME ORDER BY SUM(Store.QTY*Product.PRICE)) AS MIN_SEQ
FROM Stores INNER JOIN 
     Invoices$ 
     ON Stores.store_ID = Invoices.Store_ID INNER JOIN 
     InvDetails 
     ON Invoices.INVOICE_ID = InvDetails.INVOICE_ID INNER JOIN 
     Products 
     ON Products.PRODUCT_ID = InvDetails.PRODUCT_ID
GROUP BY Stores.Store_ID, Suppliers$.NAME;
```

By using this, you can filter out :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM ( <query here>
     ) t
WHERE (t.MAX_SEQ <= 10 OR MIN_SEQ <= 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could union your query with basically the same query, but change it to top 5 and in ascending order:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Stores.Store_ID,Suppliers$.NAME,SUM(Store.QTY*Product.PRICE) AS 
StoreSales
FROM Stores
INNER JOIN Invoices$ ON Stores.store_ID=Invoices.Store_ID
INNER JOIN InvDetails ON Invoices.INVOICE_ID=InvDetails.INVOICE_ID
INNER JOIN Products ON Products.PRODUCT_ID=InvDetails.PRODUCT_ID
GROUP BY Stores.Store_ID,Stores.NAME 
ORDER BY StoresSales DESC

UNION

SELECT TOP 5 Stores.Store_ID,Suppliers$.NAME,SUM(Store.QTY*Product.PRICE) AS 
StoreSales
FROM Stores
INNER JOIN Invoices$ ON Stores.store_ID=Invoices.Store_ID
INNER JOIN InvDetails ON Invoices.INVOICE_ID=InvDetails.INVOICE_ID
INNER JOIN Products ON Products.PRODUCT_ID=InvDetails.PRODUCT_ID
GROUP BY Stores.Store_ID,Stores.NAME 
ORDER BY StoresSales ASC
```